# Is it possible to bypass ms access maximum form width?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Microsoft Access seems to limit the form width. This limit is ->very-< small...
Is there any way to bypass this limit?

I try to create a dynamic datasheet view which allows background coloring of rows, onClick events in specific fields, Locking of specific fields, logging of changes etc. I'm using a continous form, that dynamically defines field width, events, sorting, color and position to create this perfekt table, which works really well.

The only limitation for this I've found is the max form width, wich seems to be a simple integer, 32.767 . The size of this seems to be ->much<- smaller than a pixel (I've heard it's 567 per cm.), and so it limits at about 1.2 screen witdh of a HD screen. Thats WAY to small...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 32.767 being smaller than a pixel? The max width for a form is 22 inches which is 31680 twips. That is ~1.2x the with of my monitor; you're right. But that seems pretty darn wide. Certainly not *very* small.

If you need wider than that you can use datasheet view for data entry, or multiple rows of controls in your continuous form, or multiple screens (i.e. tab ontrol, let the users click 'Next' to fill out more data).

This is a logical width to keep you from shooting your self in the foot. People don't like to scroll to the side a lot.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I needed that the form can be scrolled to the side like a table. I achieved this using a webbrowser control as form, generating the "form" as HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: This was true in 2014, but in 2019 a 22 inch monitor is pretty small. Anyone find a way around this?

Comment: @RobertLoughrey as of Access 2016 this still seems to be the limit. Though remember that 22 physical inches of screen is not the same as 22 on screen inches.

Comment: Here is the UserVoice feature request where you can vote and comment: https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/18638836-expand-the-maximum-form-width